# Trying to create an AWS policy that all allows everything except deletes

Tags: amazon-iam

I'm looking to create a policy that allows access to all AWS services except for the Delete permissions.  I see that I can do the following but you have to label every AWS service and `"*:Delete*"` doesn't work. Is there an easier way to allow all services except for the Delete permissions?

```
...
"Effect": "Allow",
  "NotAction": [
    "application-autoscaling:Delete*",
    "autoscaling:Delete*"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official IAM documentation you have to list all the services.

Based on the grammar you can either define `"NotAction": "*"` or `"NotAction": ["s3:Delete*", "ec2:Delete*", ...]`

For further info see **action_string** section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html#policies-grammar-notes) and policy grammar [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html#policies-grammar-bnf).